react emoji picker font family not working while displaying the emoji in textarea or any div but i waorking in EmojiPicker component only why?
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import EmojiPicker from 'emoji-picker-react'

const ChatBox = () =\> {

     const messageRef = useRef(null);
    
     const handleEmojiClick = (e) => { 
        if(messageRef.current){ 
            console.log(e) 
            messageRef.current.value += e.emoji 
        }
     }
    
     return (
    
         <EmojiPicker 
              className='emojiComponent' 
              height={350} width={400} 
              emojiStyle='apple'       
              suggestedEmojisMode='recent' 
              previewConfig={{ showPreview : false }} 
              searchDisabled onEmojiClick={(e) => handleEmojiClick(e)}
         /> 
    
         <textarea ref={messageRef} />
    
         <div>{messageRef.current.value}<div/>
    
     )

}

I'm building react application. In that I'm using emoji-picker-react and its emojiStyle is set to apple.
It is in apple format but when I'm accessing and displaying in textarea or any div then it is in native font family but i want apple format in textarea or anywhere while displaying the selected emoji.
WHY????
I want to replace system default emoji with my emoji picker Component emojiStyle that is apple
actually it is showing apple style in only emoji-picker-react component but i want every where in my react application
So please any one tell me how to set emoji style to apple in my react website
Any one resolve my issue!...

use state
const ChatBox = () => {
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState("")
  const handleEmojiClick = (e) => {
    setMsg(pre => pre + e.emoji)
  }

  return (
    ...
    <textarea value={msg} onChange={(e) => setMsg(e.target.value)} />
  )
}


Here the prbm is not with useRef I want to set Apple font family to emojis in react website instead of default font family which is native
